# How to get the 360 degree of two vectors

Tags: javascript

I am getting the angle of two vectors.

code returns

```
90 = 1.57 
180 = 3.14
```

It's ok,however

```
270 = 1.57
```

This would be the same `90`, I want to distinguish 90 / 270.

Where should I fix?

```
getAngle(a,b){

    var dot = a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;

    var absA = Math.sqrt(a.x*a.x + a.y*a.y);
    var absB = Math.sqrt(b.x*b.x + b.y*b.y);

    var cosTheta = dot / (absA*absB);

    var theta = Math.acos(cosTheta);
    
    console.log("force theta:",theta);
    return theta;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the angle of two vectors"?

Comment: @AKX he means the formula v1.v2 = |v1||v2|cos(theta). theta is angle between two vectors

Comment: What would be the input and output ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with expected inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.acos()` returns the [*interior angle*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.acos), so because `cos` is an even function you need to subtract from `2pi` to get the exterior angle.

```
var theta = 2*Math.PI - Math.acos(cosTheta);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solves it by using the Math method `.atan2()` which returns results in the range from -PI to +PI:

```js
const dot=(a,b)=>a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y,  // inner vector product
        x=(a,b)=>a.x*b.y-a.y*b.x   // vector cross product
      ang=(a,b)=>Math.atan2(x(a,b),dot(a,b))*180/Math.PI, 
      // a few sample vectors:
      a={x:2,y:2},b={x:-3,y:3},c={x:-4,y:0},d={x:0,y:-5};

console.log(ang(a,b));
console.log(ang(a,c));
console.log(ang(a,d));
```

If you want the resulting angle to be in the range from 0 to 2 PI (0 to 360 degrees) you can do it like this:

```js
const ang=(a,b)=>(360+Math.atan2(a.x*b.y-a.y*b.x,a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y)*180/Math.PI)%360, 
// a few sample vectors:
      a={x:2,y:2},b={x:-3,y:3},c={x:-4,y:0},d={x:0,y:-5},e={x:1,y:0};

console.log(ang(a,b)); //  90
console.log(ang(a,c)); // 135
console.log(ang(a,d)); // 225
console.log(ang(a,e)); // 315
console.log(ang(e,a)); //  45  // the arguments' order is significant!
```